# How can I create a webapi with nested xml from ssms table?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, nested

I have made a web api with C# and an ssms table. The result is an xml with only elements.

```
//This is only an example


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

How can I format my xml as nested like this and add an optional different header from ssms table element??:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
       <example>
        <from>Jani
         <heading>Reminder</heading>
        </from>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
      </example>
    </note>
```

Comment: And why exactly is it that you want such a format? It seems you can manually add the heading tag withing your <from /> field, but what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @FreekW. I'm afraid it's a standard and I should do it like this automatically with c#..:)

Comment: `<from>Jani<heading>Reminder</heading></from>` Like this? Because I just create datacontracts and serialize those classes and they fill them like this `<from><heading>Reminder</heading></from>` Because data should be added in variable not the collection.

Comment: @Freek W. like this yeah, this was only an example..I wanted to have a way, not a 
ready solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication78
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xml = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<note>" +
                    "<to>Tove</to>" +
                    "<from>Jani</from>" +
                    "<heading>Reminder</heading>" +
                    "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>" +
                "</note>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement from = doc.Descendants("from").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement heading = doc.Descendants("heading").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement body = doc.Descendants("body").FirstOrDefault();

            from.Add(heading);

            XElement example = new XElement("example", new object[] {from,body});
            heading.Remove();
            body.Remove();
            from.ReplaceWith(example);


        }
    }
}
```

---

If you are creating from scratch

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication78
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><note></note>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement note = doc.Root;

            note.Add(new XElement("to", "Tove"),
                new XElement("example", new object[] {
                    new XElement("from", new object[] {
                        "Jani", new XElement("heading", "Reminder")
                    }),
                    new XElement("body","Don't forget me this weekend!")
                })
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much...I don't want to do this for every single xml and parse it!
But I want it to be produced in a specific way, from different ssms table elements!

Comment: I update code to show how to generate from scratch.  You can use the SQLClient DataAdapter method to create a DataTable.  The use the DataTable WriteXml() method to same DataTable to a file.